# SIGABRT xcode 4.2 error

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, sigabrt

I am trying to run my app for IPhone in xcode 4.2 and it keeps shutting down. From what I've heard, SIGABRT can come from many places. I have tried restarting the computer and resetting the iOS simulator already. The build succeeds, but then pops out this error before I can test the app. The error is in the main.m file.

> 0x00001fa8  <+0152>  mov    -0x38(%ebp),%ecx

Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Comment: Have you done any other debugging efforts? Setting breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT means that there was an error thrown somewhere in your code. This could happen due to a wide range of problems. Try setting an exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator or manually set breakpoints yourself to see where the exception was thrown. Also you can look in the debugger console to see where the exception came from.